# `hcitool con` does not find any devices when run in the context of a udev script

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth, raspbian, udev

I'm trying to automate a task to configure a bluetooth device when it's connected to my raspberry pi 3 running raspbian.

Assuming `$x` is the address of the device, I need to execute the following commands after it connects:

```
hcitool enc $x off
hcitool sr $x slave
```

The initial bluetooth connection info (from running `hcitool con`) looks like this:

```
Connections:
    > ACL $x handle 11 state 1 1m MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

And after running the above two commands, `hcitool con` shows the desired state:

```
Connections:
    > ACL $x handle 11 state 1 1m SLAVE AUTH
```

I was able to get a basic udev rule to execute a script, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

Here's the udev rule at /etc/udev/rules.d/99-slave.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", RUN+="/home/pi/fix-bluetooth.bash"
```

And the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
hcitool con >> /tmp/hello_world
```

Then I `tail -f /tmp/hello_world` and plug/unplug my bluetooth device and this is what I see:

```
Connections:
Connections:
Connections:
...
```

etc.

I've tried adding `sleep` for a few seconds. I've tried adding sudo. I've tried it with multiple bluetooth devices attached. I can never get `hcitool con` to output anything when executed as part of a udev rule.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I have same issue

Comment: I ended up with a cron job to do the same instead of a udev script.